# iOS Safari weird behavior of focusing input, centering input on focusing

Tags: ios, input, safari, uiscrollview, focus

for the last few days I am trying to fix a very weird problem that occurs just on iOS Safari. (14/15 and 16+)

Ill post a video clip here to explain it.

Bugged behaviour: https://streamable.com/11l02b

Normal behaviour: https://streamable.com/frg809

So as you can see sometimes (it doesn't happen all the time) focusing on input safari tries to pull the input to the center which bugs out elastic and pull to refresh option.

Any suggestions how to completely fix the problem ? Thanks in advance.

I'v tried prevent scrolling when focus with opacity 0, didn't help.

```
input:focus {
  animation: blink_input_opacity_to_prevent_scrolling_when_focus 0.1s;
}

@keyframes blink_input_opacity_to_prevent_scrolling_when_focus {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Also after spending 2 days I have found out that turning off PullToRefresh completely fix this problem. Because the problem occurs when focusing on input is trying to center the screen but it bugs out pull to refresh.

`body { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: none; overscroll-behavior: none; }`

But then over-scroll and pull to refresh is completely gone which doesn't suits as solution because its breaking normal iOS users behaviour