# Sticky sub-headers on a page with fixed page header

Tags: css, sticky

I have a web page with a fixed top-of-page header (website name, menu, etc.) and content that has sub-headers that I'd like to be sticky. I've thought of two ways of doing this in CSS, and neither works:

1. Use `position: fixed` or `position: sticky` for the page header. This causes the rest of the page to scroll underneath the page header, and so its sub-headers aren't visible when they stick. They stick to the top of the *page* (which is underneath the page header), not to the top of their own visible section.

   When specifying the sticky sub-header, I could make `top` equal to the height of the page header. This fixes the stickiness at the expense of having to know the height (in my case it's variable).

   Another drawback of this approach is that the page scrollbar extends into the page header instead of being restricted to the scrolling section.
2. Use flex or grid or whatever to break the page vertically into two sections, the header and a scrollable main section. This causes the sub-headers to properly stick to the top of the main section, but has two problems. One is that `#fragments` no longer work reliably, because the anchors are inside a nested scrolling block. The second, more serious problem, is that it triggers all sorts of bugs in mobile Safari where the browser tries to vertically center focused text input fields, and it does that by forcing the entire page to scroll (rather than just the main section). Once this happens the view is stuck and the page must be reloaded to get it to scroll properly again. Here's [someone else's StackOverflow bug about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76136438/ios-safari-weird-behavior-of-focusing-input-centering-input-on-focusing) and [their video of the problem](https://streamable.com/11l02b). (That bug can happen without the nested scrolling div, but is much worse with it.)

Seems like a fixed page header is a very common thing, and wanting sticky sub-headers is a common thing, and I can't get both. I've investigated various high-profile mobile websites (Google Docs, reddit, StackOverflow, MDN), and they all use option #1 above and forego sticky sub-headers.

Any ideas for how to get sticky sub-headers to work without making my own nested scrolling block? Or for how to get around Safari's scrolling bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using solution #1, with `position: sticky` for the page header and a non-zero `top` property on the sticky sub-headers. Since the value of the `top` property should be the height of the page header, and that height is variable, I used TypeScript to set it:

```
function configureStickyHeaders() {
    const pageHeader = document.querySelector(".pageHeader");
    if (pageHeader === null) {
        return;
    }

    let stylesheet: HTMLStyleElement | undefined = undefined;

    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
        // We only observe a single element.
        if (entries.length !== 1 || entries[0].borderBoxSize.length !== 1) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the height of the page header.
        const height = entries[0].borderBoxSize[0].blockSize;

        // Make a new stylesheet to apply to all sub-headers.
        if (stylesheet !== undefined) {
            stylesheet.remove();
        }
        stylesheet = document.createElement("style");
        stylesheet.innerHTML= `
            .sub-header {
                top: ${height}px;
            }
        `;
        document.body.append(stylesheet);
    });

    resizeObserver.observe(pageHeader);
}
```

The observer triggers immediately, so there's no need to otherwise initialize the `top` property.

This approach still has the drawback of the scrollbar going to the very top of the page, but that's minor.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code I can't make any define answer but from what I am reading option #1 is way to go.

Usually, `position: sticky` on the navigation header bar will automatically push down the main container and if that doesn't and covering your subheader and content, you can always add top padding to push down your main section content down (including your subheader).

Say this is your code,

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">Page Header</nav>
<main class="main-content">Your main content with subheader</main>
</body>
```

If use `position: fixed`:

`.navbar {position: fixed; top: 0; height: 100px; z-index: 9999}`

`.main-content { padding-top: 100px; (if your page header is 100px height) }`

Also, adjust your padding according to your breakpoints.

Comment: This has the problem I mentioned in point #1, which is that sticky headers slip underneath the page header. See https://jsfiddle.net/lkesteloot/xj7grmva/7/ But this made me realize that I could set the top of the sticky header to 100px. Not ideal since I'd prefer CSS to figure that out for me instead of hard-coding it (it's variable).